# How to rearrange a column with thousands of rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, match

I want to rearrange column "x2" in the order "2016,2017,2018". However, the function match only rearranges 3 rows in column x2. Please, how do i rearrange all the rows in column x2 ?.

**step 1**

```
g <- data.frame("x1" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                "x2" = c(2018,2017,2016,2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018),
                "x3" = c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29))

**step 2**

v <- c(2016,2017,2018)

**step 3**

h <- g[match(v,g$x2),]

**step 4**

View(h)
```

I am using a large dataset but this is a sample of my data.

I want column x2 be arranged as

2016
2017
2018
2016
2017
2018
2016
2017
2018

Comment: But what order should the other columns be in for the desired output? How do you decide which order the rows go in? If you have three 2016 rows, which goes 1st, 4th, 7th?

Comment: The order of the other columns do not matter. I want all the rows in column x2 to be 2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little helper function

```
cycle_order <- function(x) {
  order(ave(x, x, FUN=seq_along), x)
}
```

This function will sort values by their occurrence numbers and then value. You can then use this in place of a normal order

```
g$x2[ cycle_order(g$x2) ]
# [1] 2016 2017 2018 2016 2017 2018 2016 2017 2018
```

or use it on the whole data.frame

```
g[ cycle_order(g$x2), ]
#   x1   x2 x3
# 3  3 2016 23
# 2  2 2017 22
# 1  1 2018 21
# 4  4 2016 24
# 5  5 2017 25
# 6  6 2018 26
# 7  7 2016 27
# 8  8 2017 28
# 9  9 2018 29
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

g %>% 
  mutate(temp = row_number(), .by = x2) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  arrange(x2, .by_group = TRUE) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-temp)
```

Output:

```
     x1    x2    x3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3  2016    23
2     2  2017    22
3     1  2018    21
4     4  2016    24
5     5  2017    25
6     6  2018    26
7     7  2016    27
8     8  2017    28
9     9  2018    29
```