# How to make rows follow a pattern in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like column x1 to follow a pattern. In column x1, I want to make the next row 2017 if the previous row in column is 2018. Also, If the previous row is 2016, I want the next row to be 2018.

```
g <- data.frame("x1" = c(2018,"NA",2016,2016,"NA",2018,2017,2016,"NA"),
                "x2" = c(2,2,2,1,4,3,4,1,1),
                "x3" = c(22,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29))
```

I am using a large dataset but this is a sample of my data.

Expected results:

```
g <- data.frame("x1" = c(2018,2017,2016,2016,2018,2018,2017,2016,2018),
                "x2" = c(2,2,2,1,4,3,4,1,1),
                "x3" = c(22,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29))
```

Comment: Are your values actually the character `"NA"` or are they missing `NA` values? Also, you seem to have multiple questions all centered on these type of data and basic data manipulation ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76055421/how-to-rearrange-two-columns-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76045848/how-to-rearrange-a-column-with-thousands-of-rows-in-r)) - these aren't bad questions but basic and this site is meant as a "last resort," it may be worthwhile for you to review basic data manipulation functions in R and try out a few things yourself before asking. Good luck!

Comment: they are missing "NA" values. I will review the data manipulation functions. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your "NA" values are `NA`, one approach is to use `dplyr::case_when` inside `dplyr::mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

g2 <- g %>%
  mutate(x1 = case_when(
    is.na(x1) & lag(x1) == 2018 ~ 2017,
    is.na(x1) & lag(x1) == 2016 ~ 2018,
    TRUE ~ x1
  ))
```

Output:

```
    x1 x2 x3
1 2018  2 22
2 2017  2 22
3 2016  2 23
4 2016  1 24
5 2018  4 25
6 2018  3 26
7 2017  4 27
8 2016  1 28
9 2018  1 29
```

If they were truly character variables `"NA"` as in your example data, you would simply change the above code to:

```
g <- g %>%
  mutate(x1 = case_when(
    x1 == "NA" & lag(x1) == "2018" ~ "2017",
    x1 == "NA" & lag(x1) == "2016" ~ "2018",
    TRUE ~ x1
  ))
```

Comment: Great! If this answered your question and there are no better answers, please mark it as completed so others in the community know this is closed out and keep the site cleaned up (click the check mark by the question) you may want to go back to your old questions and do the same). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

We could do it this way:
Here we use `case_when`. Before we transform x1 to numeric by using `type.conver(as.is = TRUE)`, then apply the conditions as given:

```
library(dplyr)

g %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(x1 = case_when(is.na(x1) & lag(x1) == 2018 ~2017,
                        is.na(x1) & lag(x1) == 2016 ~2018,
                        TRUE ~ x1))

    x1 x2 x3
1 2018  2 22
2 2017  2 22
3 2016  2 23
4 2016  1 24
5 2018  4 25
6 2018  3 26
7 2017  4 27
8 2016  1 28
9 2018  1 29
```